# MongoDB multiple/single collection and MySQL advice

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I have a project which is using NodeJS and I have different entities for example, people and places.

1. I need the ability to find both types of entities by location together so what I was thinking of doing is having an index on a field called, *type*, for example, which would be either *person* or *place* and make use geospatial indexes, does this sound a good way to do this or is there a better way?
2. I will probably need a lot of joins too, so should I use MySQL alongside MongoDB and use MongoDB just for delivering the location based queries?

Thanks

Comment: The coding isn't an issue, it's just advice on whether it's a good way to structure and organise data and if there are any significant performance implications in the way I'm planning on doing it

Comment: the problem is that advice without showing what you have done is prohibited here. I do not necessarily agree with this (because sometimes I would like to know what is the best tool or how other people would like to do this task) but this is the rule here. So good question should show what have you done and what is your problem. Not just I have to do this task, show me how to do it.

Comment: Doesn't MySQL have geo queries now? 1 sounds reasonable but 2 sounds totally unresearched and like you don't really know what your doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a poor fit for stackoverflow, but here's some radom bullet points:

1. PostgreSQL supports both joins and geospatial. I'd pick that first personally lacking other details warranting a different data store.
2. A totally valid option would be to keep people and places separate and query multiple collections as necessary. However, if you need to sort the results, then yes best to throw them in the same collection.
3. You could also keep people and places in separate mongodb collections but have a mapreduce job translate them into a locations collection for search purposes.

Generally, there are lots of ways to do this and the best one depends very much on the specific aspects of you application. Reads vs writes, data stability, data size, query load, etc, etc.

My broad word of advice is start with the most logical, easiest-to-follow, straightforward data organization (separate collections), and deviate from that when you understand the specific pain you have and how doing something more complicated or unusual will be an overall win.